# Celery interval schedule time

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am using django celery beat to schedule my task . 
Currently i am just creating a interval schedule of 2 days and creating a periodic task to run at that interval .

My main problem is , when i schedule a task to run at 2 days , at what time does it run ? and cant i change that time , because i need to run the interval task at certain time provided by the user . 
The code written so far is

```
        periodic_task=PeriodicTask.objects.update_or_create(
            name='my-interval-task,
            defaults={
                'interval': schedule, #interval schedule object 
                'task': 'myapp.tasks.auto_refresh',
            }
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [crontab class](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules)

Eg. `schedule = crontab(hour=0, minute=0, day_of_month='2-30/3')` fires every even numbered day at midnight